# If we take $f$ be integrable function then can we prove $\int_{\Bbb R} f(x)\cos(nx)dx \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma i.e http://kurser.math.su.se/pluginfile.php/15735/mod_resource/content/1/RiemannLebesgueVretblad.pdf in this link

If we take $f$ to be an (improperly) integrable function then can we prove $\int_{\Bbb R} f(x)\cos(nx)dx \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Note here $f$ is not absolutely convergent. I am thinking that we will have a problem when we move to unboundedness of $\mathbb R$ otherwise in a compact subset of $\mathbb R$ we will not have any problem. But I can't find any counter-example.

Comment: Isn't it the case that $f$ integrable iff $\int |f| < \infty$?

Comment: @Trevor Norton For him (and the article) this is absolutely integrable.

Comment: @nicomezi I guess I don't understand what "absolutely integrable in the Riemann sense" is for an infinite interval. I was just wondering if we could assume $f$ was absolutely integrable or not.

Comment: You meant $f$ is not absolutely integrable.

Comment: How about $f(x) = \cos(x^2/4\pi)$?

Answer (score 4):

Let me actually expand my comment to an answer. Choose $f(x) = \cos(x^2/4\pi)$. [It is well-known](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) that $f$ is improperly integrable on $\Bbb{R}$. To be precise, we have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx = \pi \sqrt{2}$. Now

\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\cos(nx) \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Big( \cos( \tfrac{1}{4\pi}x^2 + nx ) + \cos( \tfrac{1}{4\pi}x^2 - nx ) \Big) \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Big( \cos( \tfrac{1}{4\pi}(x + 2\pi n)^2 - \pi n^2 ) + \cos( \tfrac{1}{4\pi}(x - 2\pi n)^2 - \pi n^2 ) \Big) \, dx \\
&= \frac{(-1)^n}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( f(x + 2\pi n) + f(x - 2\pi n) \right) \, dx \\
&= (-1)^n I
\end{align*}

and therefore the integral does not converge as $n \to \infty$.